# Passing dynamic select values to cursor in SQL (cursor usage)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm new to cursors,

How should I write my below code in cursor to pass column value to variable @str

Basically @str in below code is taking static value, need to pass table column values

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(1000), 
          @str1 VARCHAR(1000), 
          @str2 VARCHAR(1000), 
          @pos INT, 
          @counter INT 

SET @str = '45 | 00055 | 9/30/2016 | Vodafone | Randy Singh | Newyork | Test Msg | TBL101 | PC | 1.00 | COMP101 | CS | 1.00.............. etc'

(Here i need to pass table column value like--- select name from Order so every time it takes new value)

--select @str = temp FROM OrderTemp

SET @counter = 0 
SET @pos = 0 

WHILE @counter <= 6
BEGIN   
SET @pos = CHARINDEX('|', @str, @pos + 1)   
SET @counter = @counter + 1 
END 

SET @str1 = SUBSTRING(@str, 1, @pos) 
SET @str2 = SUBSTRING(@str, @pos+1, LEN(@str)-@pos) 

insert into OrderInterface (name)(SELECT @str2)
insert into OrderInterface (Id)(SELECT @str1)
```

**Input**

```
@str :-- '45 | 00055 | 9/30/2016 | Vodafone | Randy Singh | Newyork | Test Msg | TBL101 | PC | 1.00 | COMP101 | CS | 1.00.............. etc'

Now i need to pass Input value from table like : Select name from tablename instead of static values.
```

### Ouput

```
@str1 :-- '45 | 00055 | 9/30/2016 | Vodafone | Randy Singh | Newyork | Test Msg'

@str2 :-- 'TBL101 | PC | 1.00 | COMP101 | CS | 1.00.............. etc'
```

Comment: The best way to do this is to **avoid** cursors altogether. 99% of the time you really don't need a cursor....

Comment: Since you are new to cursors you should use a set based and continue to be inexperienced with cursors. They are the work of the devil.

Comment: if not cursors then how should i pass each value to @str

Comment: What is is your input and expected output?

Comment: Input is @str in the given code and output are @-str1 and @-str2 those I'm inserting into table

Comment: no... what is your input.  actual values -- giving variable names means nothing to us since we don't know what you are trying to do.  you have to explain what you are trying to do.  If you don't explain what you are trying to do we can't help.

Comment: Input is @str='45 | 00055 | 9/30/2016 | Vodafone | Randy Singh | Newyork | Test Msg | TBL101 | PC | 1.00 | COMP101 | CS | 1.00.............. etc'

Ouput is @str1= '45 | 00055 | 9/30/2016 | Vodafone | Randy Singh | Newyork | Test Msg'

@str2= 'TBL101 | PC | 1.00 | COMP101 | CS | 1.00.............. etc'

It just splitting based on 6th element. Now i need to pass @str as column values from table not as i'm giving directly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Assuming #Temp looks something like this:

[image]

Then we can do the following:

```
;with cte as (
              Select A.RN,B.* 
               From  (Select *,RN = Row_Number() over(Order By (Select NULL)) From #Temp) A
               Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Temp,' | ') B
             )
-- Insert Into OrderInterface  (Name,ID)
Select Name = (Select String1=Stuff((Select  ' | ' + RetVal From cte Where RN=A.RN and RetSeq<=7 For XML Path ('')),1,3,'') )
      ,ID =   (Select String1=Stuff((Select  ' | ' + RetVal From cte Where RN=A.RN and RetSeq>7  For XML Path ('')),1,3,'') )
 From cte A
 Group By A.RN
```

**Which Returns**

[image]

---

**The UDF if Needed**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot john. I was looking for the same. 

You always help me :)

Comment: @SomashekharKendule Happy to help.  Cheers.

Comment: nice answer.  look, no cursor!

Comment: @Hogan High praise from someone of your stature.  I'd sooner stick a needle in my eye than use a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you are trying to do is find the 6th element in a string deliminated by `|`.

If that is the case you should not use a loop (as is always the case in SQL) instead in SQL Server you can use the STRING_SPLIT function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) like this:

```
SELECT value  
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@sql, ' | ')  
OFFSET ROWS 5 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Comment: STRING_SPLIT is not builtin function in SQL server 2008

Comment: @SomashekharKendule - a simple google search would locate a stub prior to updating to current version.

Comment: @SomashekharKendule - you will also find answers that translate the string into xml and then use the xml query functions to solve this kind of problem.